# Output HTML table elements separated by commas in PHP

Tags: php, html-table, html-parsing

My code strips td elements from an html table and outputs them in a single line.

Here is an html table my code extracts td values from:

```
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#006699">
<tr align="center" class="tableRow1Font">
<td width="7%">WAITLIST</td>
<td width="5%">91630</td>
<td width="11%">
ACCY <A HREF="http://www.gwu.edu/~bulletin/ugrad/accy.html#2001" target="_blank">2001</A>
</td>
<td width="5%">10</td>
<td width="16%">Intro Financial Accounting</td>
<td width="6%">3.00</td>
<td width="8%"> Zou, Y</td>
<td width="8%"><A HREF="http://www.gwu.edu/~map/building.cfm?BLDG=DUQUES" target="_blank"
>DUQUES</a> 251</td>
<td width="13%">TR<br>09:35AM - 10:50AM</td>
<td width="14%">
01/13/14 - 04/28/14
</td>
<td width="7%">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My code that takes these td values and outputs them on their own line. Keep in mind this is only one table of many in my .html file. Here is my code:

```
$html = file_get_html('badm.html');

$str = '';

foreach($html->find('table tr[align="center"]') as $e)
    $str .= strip_tags($e->innertext) . '<br>';
        echo $str;
```

The output looks like this (each line is a separate table in my badm.html file): 
[image: Function Output]

My question is this: How can I separate each td element with a single comma WHILE keeping them in the same format above (on their own line)?

Comment: I remember this yesterday, do these tables have a set number of columns? or varying?

Comment: All I need are the first 10 columns. So a set 10 could work....

Comment: I think that will work what I just answered, I didn't test it however

Comment: Its really pretty close, here is what the output looks like: http://imgur.com/ylLgu7o It's breaking to a new line at each of the times. Why would that be?

Comment: Can you make the zoom a bit better haha, I can't read very well

Comment: I edited where the trim occurs, check to see what the output would be. It should only be <br> after each row

Comment: Hmmm didn't seem to do much: http://imgur.com/ZqL0Rck

Comment: I figured it out, this `<td width="13%">TR<br>09:35AM - 10:50AM</td>` has a <br> in it so you have to strip the tags to get rid of it ;) (updated answer)

Comment: Dude, you are the man. I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: No problem my friend! Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_html('badm.html');
$str = '';
foreach($html->find('table tr[align="center"]') as $e)
{
  foreach($e->find('td') as $f)
  {
   $str .= strip_tags($f->innertext) . ',';
  }
$str = trim($str, ",");
$str .= '<br>';
}
echo $str;
```